# Почему не работает JS регулярное выражение в HTML pattern?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, html5

Из-за чего выражение `^(\+7|8)(\(\d{3}\)|\s\d{3}-|\d{5})(\d{5}|\s?\d{3}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})$` работает на всевозможных площадках по проверке регулярок (например [regex101.com](http://regex101.com)), но не работает в аттрибуте `pattern` у инпута?

```js
$("form").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log('valid');
   return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="tel" name="name" placeholder="Телефон"
       pattern="^(\+7|8)(\(\d{3}\)|\s\d{3}-|\d{5})(\d{5}|\s?\d{3}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})$" />
   <input type="submit" value="ok"/>
 </form>
```

Comment: А какое значение не проходит проверку?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew дак все проходят, даже строки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Регулярное выражение в атрибуте HTML5 *pattern* компилируется в FireFox и Chrome с флагом `u`. Этот флаг более требовательный к синтаксису выражения, нельзя экранировать что угодно, **нужно экранировать только специальные метасимволы регулярных выражений**.

*Вне символьных классов* необходимо экранировать `.`, `^`, `$`, `*`, `+`, `?`, `(`, `)`, `[`, `{` (эту скобку можно не экранировать в большинстве случаев, но если нужно найти её, число и закрывающую фигурную скобку, то экранирование необходимо, ср. `/a\{3}/` (строка `a{3}`) != `/a{3}/` - три буквы `a`), `\` и `|`.

*Внутри символьных классов* НАДО всегда экранировать `]` и `\`, а также `-`, если этот символ не в начале или в конце класса (`[-0-9_]` = `[0-9_-]` = `[_\-0-9]`), и `^`, если этот символ в начале символьного класса (`[^0]` (любой символ, отличный от нуля) != `[\^0]` (либо `^`, либо `0`)). См. [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078) (на английском языке).

Здесь нужно удалить символы обратной косой черты перед символом `-`:

```js
$("form").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log('valid');
   return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="tel" name="name" placeholder="Телефон"
       pattern="(\+7|8)(\(\d{3}\)|\s\d{3}-|\d{5})(\d{5}|\s?\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2})" />
   <input type="submit" value="ok"/>
 </form>
```

Обратите внимание на отсутствие `^` и `$` в шаблоне: регулярное выражение в атрибуте `pattern` всегда находит совпадение только целой строки, так как весь шаблон помещается между `^(?:` и `)$` (`pattern="(\+7|8)(\(\d{3}\)|\s\d{3}-|\d{5})(\d{5}|\s?\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2})"` => `/^(?:(\+7|8)(\(\d{3}\)|\s\d{3}-|\d{5})(\d{5}|\s?\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}))$/u`). См. [документацию (на английском языке)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute).